# Problem with page numbering styles with letter page style in scrletter

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, pagestyle, scrletter

All page references here correspond to the English KOMA-Script manual, version number 2.28.

Consider the following TeX file.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,headheight=30pt,headinclude,firsthead=false,firstfoot=false,foldmarks=false,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=center,fromphone,fromemail,version=last, backaddress=false, subject=titled, twoside=semi, cleardoublepage=current]{scrletter}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\ohead{\jobname.tex\hspace{0.5cm}\today}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\ofoot*{}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\def\today{19th February, 2022}
\begin{letter}{Name}
  \opening{Dear Name,}
  \thispagestyle{scrheadings}
  \lipsum
\end{letter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The document generated with PDFLaTeX has 4 pages. My question is about
the page numbers. As you can see, the page numbers are `Page 1`, `Page 2`, `3 of 4`, `4 of 4`. This is unexpected behavior.

If one replaces `scrletter` with `scrlttr2`, one gets the expected
behavior, namely `1 of 4`, `2 of 4`, `3 of 4`, `4 of 4`.

This is probably related to the fact that `scrletter` defines its own
page styles, namely `plain.letter` and `letter`. It seems that this
page style has been created for letters that are embedded in documents
of other classes, which is the `scrletter` use case. And it also seems
that this page style silently overrides the style i've set, at least
for the page numbers. But this is all semi-guesswork. I've been
reading the manual, trying to make sense of it.

For example, in Section 4.13: "Headers and Footers with the Default
Page Style" pg 231 is written:

> scrletter letter Since the headings page style is generally already in
> use by the classes, the scrletter package instead
> defines the letter page style. This is accomplished
> with the help of scrlayer-scrpage in chapter 5, page
> 254. With the automark=true setting enabled, letter
> then assumes the role played by headings in
> scrlttr2. With automark=false set, letter assumes the
> role of myheadings.

I've read this a number of times, but it still reads like borderline
gibberish. But perhaps I haven't read it often enough. I've also read
the relevant parts of Ch 5, which make sense on their own, but I don't
see how they relate to the issue here.

On pg 229 it says:

> See section 22.2 for more information about the characteristics of
> the page style of the scrletter package.

Section 22.2 says

> Currently, additional information on this topic can be found at the
> same point in the German KOMA-Script book [Koh20a] only.

If anyone has the German book, and would like to summarize the
contents of that section, please do.

And also on pg 229, it says

> Example: You are using the scrletter package and want letters to
> use the same page style that was set for the rest of the document
> with \pagestyle. To do this, put the command
> \renewcommand{\letterpagestyle}{} in your document preamble. Notice
> the star in \renewcommand*.

This seems like it might do what I want, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `scrletter` is an undocumented wrapper-class.  It loads class `scrartcl` with font size `12pt` and package `scrletter`.

`\pagemark` is already defined by the KOMA-Script `scrartcl`. Therefore package `scrletter` defines `\letterpagemark` for the letters in the document. If the format of the page numbers in the letters should be the same as in the other part of the document, use

`\let\letterpagemark\pagemark`

before environment `letter`.

```latex
\documentclass[
  %12pt,% default
  headheight=30pt,headinclude,
  firsthead=false,firstfoot=false,
  foldmarks=false,
  %foldmarks=blmtP,% disabled by foldmarks=false
  %fromalign=center,% disabled by firsthead=false
  %fromphone,fromemail,% disabled by firsthead=false
  %version=last,
  backaddress=false,
  subject=titled,
  twoside=semi,
  cleardoublepage=current
]{scrletter}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% load by package scrletter 
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\jobname.tex\hspace{0.5cm}\usekomavar{date}}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}}
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
\AddToHook{shipout/lastpage}{\label{LastPage}}% replaces package lastpage

\renewcommand*{\letterpagestyle}{scrheadings}% page style for the next pages of the letter
\AddToHook{cmd/opening/after}{\thispagestyle{\letterpagestyle}}% use the same page style on first letter page

\setkomavar{date}{19th February, 2022}% do not change \today

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Name}
  \opening{Dear Name,}
  \thispagestyle{scrheadings}
  \lipsum
\end{letter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\letterpagestyle}{scrheadings}% page style for the next pages of the letter
\AddToHook{cmd/opening/after}{\thispagestyle{\letterpagestyle}}% use the same page style on first letter page
```

can be replaced by

```latex
\renewcommand*\letterpagestyle{}% do not change the page style for the letter
\AddToHook{cmd/opening/after}{\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}% use scrheadings on first letter page
```

The result would be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful explanation. It was very educational. First, I didn't realise I was using so many options for the `scrletter` class (and the `scrlttr2` class) which were unnecessary. I wanted to make one observation. I think your line `\thispagestyle{scrheadings}` is unnecessary, given that you have essentially written the same thing in the `\AddToHook{cmd/opening/after}` line. I tested it, and as far as I can see, your code works exactly the same without the `\thispagestyle` line.

Comment: I was also not aware of the hook functionality, like `\AddToHook`. Apparently this is quite new.

Comment: @FaheemMitha You are right: `\AddToHook{cmd/opening/after}{\thispagestyle{scrheadings}` and `\thispagestyle{scrheadings}` next to `\opening` does the same. Only one of them is needed. The new general hook management system in LaTeX was introduced in  2020 ( see https://www.latex-project.org/latex3/ and https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/lthooks-doc.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I asked about hooks in TeX SE Chat, and someone pointed me to `lthooks`. I wasn't aware of this previously. Thank you. Also, which of those two options do you think is better? `\AddToHook` or `\thispagestyle`?